# Hardware for exhibition video playback (long period) with timecode output

Tags: video, hardware

Not sure if this is the right place for such a question, but not able to find a more fitting place.

I'm looking for some solid and simple video playback hardware, for playing video continously for a long time. I'd rather not use a full computer, as experience shows that it creates more problems than a dedicated video/media player. I've previously used the [Akman AMA 1080p](http://www.akman.com/product/AMA1080p.html) which works great. But the problem now is that I wan't to create a secondary display (iPad or similar) that shows the remaining time of the movie being shown. So I would need some sort of signal output from the player with the current timecode of the video. Do anyone know of such a player? The output can be in any format, I can program the display solution myself. I can do this with the video played by a computer, but would rather not use this method as it's more unstable.